# Add list of selected items in select menu

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-components

I found this very nice example of a Angular search menu.

```
          <ui-select ng-model="ctrl.person.selected" theme="bootstrap">
            <ui-select-match placeholder="Select or search a person in the list...">{{$select.selected.name}}</ui-select-match>
            <ui-select-choices repeat="item in ctrl.people | filter: $select.search">
              <div ng-bind-html="item.name | highlight: $select.search"></div>
              <small ng-bind-html="item.email | highlight: $select.search"></small>
            </ui-select-choices>
          </ui-select>
```

[Working example in web editor](http://plnkr.co/edit/SPMetd7SBRbuX04MNn4k?p=preview)

I would like to extend the example and add a list of selected items from the select menu. Can you give me hand to implement this feature?

Comment: Please explain the problem clearly, otherwise you'll only be downvoted

Comment: The problem is how I can add a list of selected items below the select menu?

Comment: @PeterPenzov I think you should review the tags you have for your question, because according with the code, you are using AngularJS that is very different from Angular

Comment: Do you mean to select multiple values from dropdown?

Comment: Yes, can you show me example, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code will make your dropdown multiple select and will display list of slected values from dropdown

```
 <body class="ng-cloak" ng-controller="DemoCtrl as ctrl">
      Selected:<p ng-repeat="item in ctrl.person.selected"> {{item.name}}</p>

      <form class="form-horizontal">
        <fieldset>
          <legend>ui-select inside a Bootstrap form</legend>    
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Default</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">    

              <ui-select ng-model="ctrl.person.selected" theme="bootstrap" multiple="true">
                <ui-select-match placeholder="Select or search a person in the list...">{{$item.name}}</ui-select-match>
                <ui-select-choices repeat="item in ctrl.people | filter: $select.search">
                  <div ng-bind-html="item.name | highlight: $select.search">
                  </div>                  
                  <small ng-bind-html="item.email | highlight: $select.search"></small>
                </ui-select-choices>
              </ui-select>

            </div>
          </div>        
        </fieldset>
      </form>
    </body>
```

ui-select library gives multiple attribute for enabling multiple selection

[For detail documentation for *ui-select* multiple selection click here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/wiki/ui-select)

Hope this helps.